# How can I update a remote server after a local commit & push in Git?

Tags: git, github

I want my server to fetch and pull new commits/pushes from local automatically. How do I accomplish that with a hook?

Currently, if I want to make a change, I save the file, add a commit message, push it. That updates my github repo. However, my server is now out of date of this recent change and I have to ssh into server and run command: git fetch, to determine if there are any changes and then git pull to bring it up to date.

I would like to simplify this process by the server automatically updating (pulling from github) after a change has been added (pushed locally).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+hook+push+to+deploy

Comment: I already looked at that and that was not helpful...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first element to check is whether your server is reachable from GitHub.

Because if it is, you can either:

- declare a [webhook](https://docs.github.com/en/developers/webhooks-and-events/webhooks/about-webhooks), which will make GitHub send a JSON payload on each pushed commit received. If you have set up a [webhook listener](https://github.com/adnanh/webhook) on your server, you can receive that payload, and trigger the pull
- declare a GitHub Action like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65371846/6309) which can push to your server bare repository, with a [post-receive hook](https://git-scm.com/docs/githooks#post-receive) like [that one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11323004/6309) to update your live site.